# SharePoint MySite - Changing the notification email

Tags: sharepoint-enterprise, 2013, my-site, newsfeed

SharePoint 2013 sends a notification email when you first setup your MySite.  Does anyone know how can we update this email template.

I see one of the ways is to update following key in SPSCore.resx file

```
<data name="MySiteDocLibInitialSetup_GoMobile">
  <value>Take SharePoint with you by downloading the {0}mobile apps{1}.</value> 
</data>
```

But this will just change one of the strings (GoMobile).  do you know if there is a better way of achiving this.

[image: Here is the email that we receive when we setup our mysite]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I have found that the code to send this email is generated in Microsoft.Office.Server.UserProfiles.UserProfile assembly.  Refer following articles :-

- [Getting most out of SharePoint - My Site Email](http://social.technet.microsoft.com/Forums/sharepoint/en-US/32867a23-ecf0-428a-879d-8370d601f972/getting-the-most-out-of-sharepoint-my-site-email)
- [Auto-Generated SharePoint 2013 MySite Personal Site Email](http://davistrent.com/blog/Lists/Posts/Post.aspx?ID=7)

So it seems that the only way to update this email is by updating the resource files (spscore.resx and spscore.en-US.resx or any other language specific files).

The string value contains some place holders and please keep the placeholders as it is.
e.g. the above tag is update

```
<data name="MySiteDocLibInitialSetup_GoMobile">
  <value>Your text here and use the placeholder whereever you want {0}{1}</value> 
</data>
```

This will make sure that email generation code gets all the placeholders for the variable.
Search spscore.resx file for 'MySiteDocLibInitialSetup' and you will find all the value that you can update.

Hope this helps...