# Override text in emails sent by newsfeed alerts

Tags: sharepoint-enterprise, development

Working with the SharePoint social newsfeed (not Yammer). We would like to change some of the wording in the emails (such as change the word SharePoint to our specific branding) that get sent when someone does something such as follow you. I have figured out that those are stored in microsoft.office.server.intl.dll (in Resources) and not in a .resx file. Is there any way to override the resources in that dll or am I out of luck?

Comment: Similar item here:

http://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/questions/72530/sharepoint-mysite-changing-the-notification-email

Comment: That article refers to the "welcome" email that everyone gets when they create their My Site the first time. That is in a resource file you can get to. The newsfeed alert emails are in a resource file that is compiled inside a .dll (microsoft.office.server.intl).

I'm attempting to decompile, change, and recompile the .dll and see if that doesn't blow everything up.

Answer (score 0):

The solution that worked for me was de-compiling the dll (C:\Windows\Microsoft.NET\assembly\GAC_MSIL\Microsoft.Office.Server.Intl) using JetBrains dotPeek to export it as a VS 2013 project (which is basically just one resource file), making my changes to the resource file, re-compiling it as a dll, then swapping the dll files on the farm servers. Note you have to shut down the SharePoint Timer Service and World Wide Web Publishing Service to replace the dll file.

For anyone else considering this approach remember there is a risk. Any patch/update/upgrade that replaces the dll file will remove your changes and you will have to do the process all over again starting from the newly patched dll.

Comment: Certainly not a supported approach in any way. Leaving you without Microsofts help if issues arise